# How do I count how many matches from a row appear in a column in excel?

Tags: excel, match, counting

I need to count how many `Secondary Names` repeat in the `Compared List` for each `Primary List` name. So for example: For `Name 1`, no secondary names repeat in the compared list. I would like that to show a 0% in the `% Match` column. For `Name 3`, two names in the secondary name category repeat. I would like the `% Match` to show a 66% in that column.

[Here is the snap FYR..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YpZD.png)

Is there way to do it using function combination?

Please note the actual list has ~20 secondary names for each Primary list name. There are 90 primary list names. And the compared list has 800+ names.

Update: 
[Format of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZYN2.png)

Comment: Please go through this link before asking questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example picture, here is the formula for cell H2 to calculate match% for Name 1, adjust ranges as needed for your actual data.

`=SUM(IF(B2:D2=$F$2:$F$7,1,0))/COUNTA(B2:D2)`

Note: This is an array formula, so you must confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Then, just drag it down assuming your actual data is laid out in the same format.